# Select from multiple table and left join to one table

Tags: mysql, sql

Anybody can help me in solving this problem??

When im joining only 2 tables. It work fine.

[image]

but when im trying to select from multiple table. its not working. This is the example of not working code

```
SELECT ca.cdate as tarikh, sum(transaction.amount) as totalamount 
FROM agent ag, town tw, calendar ca 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON ca.cdate =  DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11' 
AND transaction.agent_id = ag.id 
AND ag.town_id = tw.id 
AND tw.state_id = 7;
```

the result is

[image]

After add the group by

```
SELECT ca.cdate as tarikh, sum(transaction.amount) as totalamount 
FROM agent ag, town tw, calendar ca 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON ca.cdate =  DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11' 
AND transaction.agent_id = ag.id 
AND ag.town_id = tw.id 
AND tw.state_id = 7
GROUP BY
ca.cdate;
```

[image]

Trying query suggest by Ambrish

```
SELECT ca.cdate as tarikh, sum(transaction.amount) as totalamount 
FROM calendar ca 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON ca.cdate = DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
LEFT JOIN agent ag on transaction.agent_id = ag.id 
LEFT JOIN town tw on ag.town_id = tw.id 
WHERE ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' 
AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11'
AND tw.state_id = 7;
```

The result is
[image]

the 2nd by Ambrish

```
SELECT ca.cdate as tarikh, sum(transaction.amount) as totalamount 
FROM calendar ca 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON ca.cdate =  DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
LEFT JOIN agent ag on transaction.agent_id = ag.id
LEFT JOIN town tw on ag.town_id = tw.id 
WHERE ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11' 
AND tw.state_id = 7
group by ca.cdate;
```

the result is

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error you are getting after running your 2nd query?

Comment: im not getting error..but only one row return and both column is null

Comment: you are missing GROUP BY

Comment: it return nothing after i add the group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
calendar.cdate,
sum(transaction.amount)
FROM
calendar
LEFT JOIN
(
    select transaction.amount, transaction.created_at from transaction, agent, town
    where
    transaction.agent_id = agent.id
    and agent.town_id = town.id
    and town.state_id = 14
)
transaction
ON calendar.cdate = DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") 
WHERE
calendar.cdate >= '2014-06-01' and calendar.cdate <= '2014-06-11'
GROUP BY
calendar.cdate;
```

Finally i manage to find the answer by using sub query..Thank you for your help..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ca.cdate as tarikh, sum(transaction.amount) as totalamount 
FROM calendar ca 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON ca.cdate =  DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
LEFT JOIN agent ag on transaction.agent_id = ag.id
LEFT JOIN town tw ag.town_id = tw.id 
WHERE ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11' 
AND tw.state_id = 7
group by ca.cdate;
```

If no results are returned then it could be possible that there are no matching records. So, try the query without (or subset of) `WHERE` clause. Or the query with different values.

Comment: actually i want to get sum of each date specified..if no transaction for the selected date..null or 0 is accepted. because i want to populate a graph..

Comment: what is the output if you remove `ca.cdate >= '2014-06-01' AND ca.cdate <= '2014-06-11' ` condition? Looks to me that there are no matching records. You can also try the query without `tw.state_id = 7` condition.